# Clases en arduino problema con el loop

Tags: c++, arduino

buen dia

Tengo un problema al hacer una clase en Arduino y es que no se repite el codigo como en un loop, me explico:

Hice una libreria que me permita controlar una serie de leds a manera de parpadeo y deseo que esa secuencia de parpadeo se repita de manera definida. Sin embargo, me he topado con el problema en el que al momento de implementarlo solo lo corre una vez y no vuelve a parpadear las veces que indico que sean. El codigo es el siguiente

Header

```
#ifndef Cluster_h
#define Cluster_h

#include "Storm.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

class Cluster{
    public:
        Cluster(int pin[]);
        void lightning(unsigned long g_glag[]);
    private:
        unsigned long currentmillis,prevmillis,g_flag[];
        int counter,u_flag;
        Storm* _led;
};



#endif
```

archivo cpp

```
#include <Cluster.h>

Cluster::Cluster(int pin[]){
    Storm led[6]={Storm(pin[0]),Storm(pin[1]),Storm(pin[2]),Storm(pin[3]),Storm(pin[4]),Storm(pin[5])};
    _led=led;
    prevmillis=0;
    counter=0;
}

void Cluster::lightning(unsigned long g_flag[]){


    while(counter<=5){  
        currentmillis=millis();

        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[0]){
            _led[0].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[1]){
            _led[1].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[2]){
            _led[2].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[3]){
            _led[3].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[4]){
            _led[4].blinkled();
        }
        if(currentmillis-prevmillis>=g_flag[5]){
            prevmillis=currentmillis;
            counter=counter+1;
        }

    }
}
```

la funcion blinkled de la clase Storm, la cual es importada desde la cabecera, es la que hace parapadear al led una cantidad de veces ya predefenida. Yo esperaria que con este codigo y al momento de implementarlo esta secuencia de parpadeos completa se repitiera 5 veces, pero solo lo hace una vez. No he encontrado la posible causa de esto, si tuvieran alguna idea del posible error seria de gran ayuda escuchar sus propuestas.

De antemano les agradezco, aqui dejo el codigo de la implementacion por si llegara a ser util.

```
#include <Cluster.h>

int p[6]={3,4,5,6,7,8};
unsigned long gf[7]={50,100,120,150,200,1000,0};
Cluster cluster(p);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  cluster.lightning(gf);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fíjate en lo que haces en tu constructor:

```
Cluster::Cluster( int pin[] ) {
  Storm led[6] = {
    Storm( pin[0] ),
    Storm( pin[1] ),
    Storm( pin[2] ),
    Storm( pin[3] ),
    Storm( pin[4] ),
    Storm( pin[5] )
  };
  _led = led;
  ...
```

Creas un *arreglo* **local a la función**, y usas su dirección para inicializar tu variable de instancia `_led`.

¿ Que pasará cuando *salgas* del constructor, y el espacio de pila ocupado por `led[]` se **reutilice para otras cosas** ? ¿ **Adonde** *apuntará* `_led` entonces ?

**EDITO**

Cambia tu constructor a esto; espero que Arduino soporte la memoria dinámica de C++ (debería):

```
Cluster::Cluster( int pin[] ){
  prevmillis = 0;
  counter = 0;

  _led[0] = new Storm( pin[0] );
  _led[1] = new Storm( pin[1] );
  _led[2] = new Storm( pin[2] );
  _led[3] = new Storm( pin[3] );
  _led[4] = new Storm( pin[4] );
  _led[5] = new Storm( pin[5] );
}
```

Y un cambio menor en tu clase:

```
class Cluster {
  ...
private:
  ...
  Storm *_led[6];
```

};

Comment: Que tal, gracias por la respuesta, pero al momento de verificar el codigo me manda un error. El error es el siguiente:

Comment: In constructor 'Cluster::Cluster(int*)':
error: no matching function for call to 'Storm::Storm()'

Comment: @INME Respuesta editada; ahora tendría que funcionar.

Comment: Hola @Trauma, de nuevo con la molestia, lo estructuro como mencionas y recibo otro error, ahora de este tipo:

In member function 'void Cluster::lightning(long unsigned int*)':
error: request for member 'blinkled' in '((Cluster*)this)->Cluster::_led[0]', which is of pointer type 'Storm*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

Comment: Ya funciona! era un problema con la clase Storm que tenia, hasta ahorita me di cuenta y no lo vi, perdona por las molestias.

Gracias!